# Validation - change background color of the parent of invalid elements

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I am using asp.net's build in validation to set required fields but rather than just displaying a message, I want to also change the background color of the invalid element's parent div.

I think I might need to use the `ClientValidationFunction` option, but I can't seem to get this to work.

Here's what I have so far...

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myOption" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" 
     ID="myOption_req" 
     ClientValidationFunction="validateMe" 
     EnableClientScript="true" 
     ControlToValidate="myOption" 
     Text="*" 
     ErrorMessage="Please fill in all required fields" />
```

With the following javascript:

```
function validateMe(){        
    alert("Hello World");      
}
```

I can't even get the alert to show yet, so can't move on to getting the parent element to change background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

### javascript

```
function validateMe(sender, arguments)
{
  if (arguments.Value == "hello world")
     arguments.IsValid = true;
  else
     arguments.IsValid = false;
}
```

### Your `aspx`

```
<asp:CustomValidator color="Red" runat="server" ID="myOption_req" 
    ClientValidationFunction="validateMe" 
    EnableClientScript="true" 
    ControlToValidate="myOption" ValidateEmptyText="true"
    Text="*" 
    ErrorMessage="Please fill in all required fields" />
```

Answer (score 0):

set color="Red" in your validation control

and change `ClientValidationFunction="javascript:validateMe();"`  instead of `ClientValidationFunction="validateMe"`

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator color="Red" runat="server" 
         ID="myOption_req" 
         ClientValidationFunction="javascript:validateMe();" 
         EnableClientScript="true" 
         ControlToValidate="myOption" 
         Text="*" 
         ErrorMessage="Please fill in all required fields" />
```

Comment: Set ValidationGroup="xx" in your button and validator control's

Answer (score 0):

`ClientValidationFunction` is not an attribute of the `RequiredFieldValidator`.

If you want some javascript to be executed, use a `CustomValidator` instead, as follows:

```
<asp:CustomValidator color="Red" runat="server" ID="myOption_req" 
    ClientValidationFunction="validateMe" 
    EnableClientScript="true" 
    ControlToValidate="myOption" ValidateEmptyText="true"
    Text="*" 
    ErrorMessage="Please fill in all required fields" />
```

Don't forget to add the `ValidateEmptyText="true"` property, otherwise the validation will be skipped if the textbox is empty.